# Using an ansible role to create two clusters

Tags: ansible

I want to setup 2 clusters of zookeepers. Right now I have a template in my zookeeper role that iterates through groups.zookeepers and builds the zookeeper config file to point to all the nodes in the cluster.
What is the right way to write one role and still get 2 separate clusters?

Comment: Could you just remove iteration from the role and apply the playbook to two separate groups independently using `--limit`?

Comment: would it be simpler to just maintain 2 inventories in that case? i was hoping to not run the playbook multiple times

Comment: that's likely to be another run (but with the `-i` flag)—sounds like @udondan's answer is much closer to what you're looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You can parameterize roles.

Example playbook snippet:

```
roles:
  - role: your_role
    cluster: A
  - role: your_role
    cluster: B
```

---

OK, after re-reding your question and above comments, I think this might be more of help:

A playbook can have multiple plays in which you can target different hosts.

```
- name: Cluster A
  hosts: clusterA
  roles:
    - your_role

- name: Cluster B
  hosts: clusterB
  roles:
    - your_role
```

Comment: are you saying - in inventory have
    [cluster1]
    node1
    [cluster2]
    node2

and then have
cluster1 map to role zookeeper with variable cluster 'A'?

in that case how do i find all other nodes only in cluster 'A' in my task under the role.

Comment: Think I first misunderstood your question. I updated my answer. Yes, when you then have two different groups in the inventory you can target them separately in two different plays in one playbook.

Comment: I understand  what you are trying to say with targeting the same role at two different groups. My main question I guess is how I can identify other members of the target inside a task in the role

Comment: Do you mean for example in a template to loop over all other hosts of the group? You can access `groups['clusterA']` which holds all the hosts of that group. I think you can not access all hosts of the current processing play, so you would nee to pass the group as a parameter to the role. See http://docs.ansible.com/faq.html#how-do-i-loop-over-a-list-of-hosts-in-a-group-inside-of-a-template

Comment: thanks. that helps.  passing the group name as a parameter would do the trick.

Comment: Actually it is possible to do it w/o passing the group name `vars['play_hosts']` should hold all hosts of the current play.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing in my hosts file
`    [cluster1]
    node1
    [cluster2]
    node2
    [cluster1:vars]
    cluster=1
    [cluster2:vars]
    cluster=2
    [zookeepers:children]
    cluster1
    cluster2
`
then in my task, i filter based on if cluster matches